# Tensorflow fails to detect GPUs

Tags: python, tensorflow, ubuntu

I have been trying to make tf/keras work with CUDA. I believe the CUDA and the Nvidia drivers are installed correctly on my Linux/ubuntu box because

1. My Julia can use the GPUs with absolutely no problem. It would be great if tf/keras would have such a wonderful configuration for GPU as Julia.
2. When I run nvidia-smi I get

NVIDIA-SMI 470.103.01   Driver Version: 470.103.01   CUDA Version: 11.4
| GPU  Name        Persistence-M| Bus-Id        Disp.A | Volatile Uncorr. ECC |

I installed the python tools for cuda, including

cudatoolkit, cudann

but when I run python and ask to tell me about the GPUs I get
tensorflow/stream_executor/platform/default/dso_loader.cc:64] Could not load dynamic library 'libcudnn.so.8

Could anyone in this forum please help?

Comment: First of all, this is not a forum, but a QA site. Your version of TensorFlow needs CUDA 8, while you have CUDA 11.4, that is why it does not work.

Answer (score 0):

I found the answer to my question below:

"Could not load dynamic library 'libcudnn.so.8'; dlerror: libcudnn.so.8: cannot open shared object file: No such file or directory"

There is a link to the CUDA repos posted by NVIDIA at the link below,

https://developer.download.nvidia.com/compute/cuda/repos/ubuntu2004/x86_64/

so I downloaded from there the Ubuntu .deb file for libcudnn.so.8

libcudnn8_8.2.2.26-1+cuda11.4_amd64.deb

installed, tested, and now things seem to be working OK